# AngularJS: http, promise (not loading fast enough)

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am using $http method and getting data which I then use on input field for autocomplete.

This data is small but it can still happen that user will be typing in this input field before data has beed loaded.

I could make $http call when user has typed something in input field. Are there any other solutions? Somehow prevent page rendering?

Comment: You could use the router's "resolve" functionality to prevent the page from loading until the data is ready. Or you could just manually hide the field and show a loading spinner until the promise resolves

Comment: Or you can make it transparent to the user - the input only get processed after your data gets in, but he still can type before it, just no response.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately I am not using router in my app. And it is already transparent, he can type without response.